# Why is it that specifically during Shovavim Do we review the Hilachos of Taharas Mishpacha/Shimiras HaBris?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, shovavim-tat

Looking for sources why is it that specifically these weeks is the time to review such Halachos in contrast to other Halachos, such as the Halachos of Shabboss,Yom Tov, Basar B'Chalav, Choshen Mishpat etc.

Comment: How do you know that it is during this time that we (?) review those topics?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. That question is about the regular wasted seed issue associated with shovavim. This question seems to ask how did that translate into cute shalom bayis drashos. Well, a least the title could've been read like that.